# Hide Class Row in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, rows

The title might sound easy but abit of a complicated question.

I have the following row which is autogenerated via some PHP:

```
<tr class="custom_field-row custom_205_-4-row"></tr>
```

The Question is:

How do i hide every instance of this row using Javascript as the no 4 is automatically replaced by other numbers depending on what entry number it is. So i need to hide:

```
<tr class="custom_field-row custom_205_-***EVERYSINGLEPOSSIBLENUMBER***-row"></tr>
```

Any Ideas? A foreach statement sounds like the best way to go forward but i am not sure where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this with a loop, it should get you all rows with

you can loop through the common part of the class and you can add your on further checks on class Name if you want to make sure its correct class or whatever

```
$('[class^="abc"]') // starts with string
$('[class$="end"]') // ends with string

$( '[class^="custom_205_"][class$="row"]').each ( function () {
   // hide this.hide() or remove
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply what about the end of the class '-row' how do we add that?

Comment: check it now i have made the changes

Comment: Thanks for your edits, i am confused on how to make the loop. Again thank you but where do i put the loop.

Comment: that you should know, after your rows are generated or before, you can make a function and then call it everytime you need it, or where you need it.